# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance" error when trying to open telerik report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, telerik, telerik-reporting

In my solution I have telerik reports and when trying to open them in Visual Studio 2010 designer, I am getting this error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance

Call Stack 

at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object instance, Attribute[] attributes)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateDesigner(IComponent component, Boolean rootDesigner)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

When I run the solution, they are appearing and they are good. So, the only problem is the designer and this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you stand a better chance of getting an answer by asking this on the peer support forums of Telerik, or raising a support issue with Telerik itself. 
http://www.telerik.com/forums/reporting

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Yes, I was aware of it. I was there before (Telerik Forum), but I could not find any help. Finally, I re-installed Telerik Reporting component, removed and added again DLLs and now is working fine. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I re-installed Telerik Reporting component, removed and added again DLLs and now is working fine.

Comment: I suspect the re-install put you on the same version that your reference was using.

Comment: Similar experience when encountering this solution on a WiseJ project as well. Reinstall the VSIX file and the previewer works again.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because the telerik library I had downloaded from the Progress control panel was the wrong version. Here's how I corrected the situation.

If you don't have the Progress Control Panel, see here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/getting-started/installation/installation-installing-from-progress-control-panel

I was working with the Telerik Reporting library and it was an older version because my company hasn't updated the license but the Progress Control Panel will download the latest by default.

To see which version you need, right click on your reference and click Properties.
[image]

The version I needed was 10.2.16.1025.

[image]

Now in Progress Control Panel, click on the library.

[image]

Now click "View All Versions"

[image]

This will show which version(s) are installed. Check "REMOVE" for a version you don't want and "INSTALL" for the version you need. Then click "CLOSE".

[image]

Then click "PROCEED" on the bottom right.

[image]

Last, I uncheck "Local Demos" unless you want them. Check "Yes, I accept..." and click "PROCEED". This will get the install/uninstall processes going.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

close visual studio and install "Telerik_Reporting.msi". then open visual studio and your project

Answer (score 2):

1. You need Just delete Telerik references.
2. Close the corrupted form.
3. Add new windows form then add a Telerik component to the new form(ex: telerikButton).
4. Open the corrupted form, wait for a second then you will find everything goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while trying to open the SQL unit test designer (non telerik related).

My 'solution' was to recreate the test and copy the contents over.

Answer (score 1):

Change the framework version of the project. I fixed the error with this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ActiveReports with a C# module.
It had worked fine in VB 2017.

Reinstalling the latest AR update solved the problem for the C# version

Comment: VB  Thank you Sir on your answer(no problems at my side anymore).